# apache2 gui / Comanche Replacement

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd, gui

I opened an OLD redhat book to the section about Apache configuration and it talked about the Comanche GUI. I thought "That's great! Why hasn't anyone suggested that before?" Then I found out that project is (apparently) dead.

Is there anything else like it that is still in development? 
If the answer is "Google it", I'd appreciate a hint as to what search terms to try.